# Bag of features and Neural Networks in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, matlab-cvst

I've been trying to implement a neural network in Matlab that is capable of recognizing images based on their features. I am attempting to use the Bag of features/words approach to obtain a discrete vector of features that I can then feed into my neural network.

I have been using this example as a guide - http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-bag-of-features.html

One line in the code (featureVector = encode(bag, img);) counts the word occurrences in an image. Could I use this "featurevector" matrix to train my neural network? And would I have to encode every single image in my training set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that's certainly possible.  By looking at the example, the training dataset is a set of images and you are finding a common vocabulary of 500 "words" / features that describes all of them with adequacy.  By using `featureVector = encode(bag, img);`, what you are doing is you are determining what fraction of each word exists to describe the input image `img`.  Specifically, if you look at the code in that example section, they plot a bar graph where the horizontal axis represents the word index and the vertical axis represents what fraction each word / feature in the vocabulary is used to represent that image.

Specifically, this is the bar graph that gets produced (taking from the link):

[image]
<sub>(source: [mathworks.com](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/examples/vision_product/ImageCategoryClassificationExample_02.png))</sub>

Therefore, similar images should be described with similar features / words and so you could certainly use this as input into your neural network.

However, before you train your neural network, as you suspected, you **must** represent every image you wish to train with this feature vector.  If you intend to use MATLAB's neural network toolbox, you must make sure that each **column** is an input sample and each **row** is a feature.  `featureVector` would actually return a `1 x N` vector where `N` is the total number of features.  However, if you want to do this more smartly, simply create an `imageSet` of all of the images you want to transform: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/imageset-class.html, then use one call to `encode` to create this desired feature matrix:

```
imgFolder = '...'; %// Specify image folder here
imgSet = imageSet(imgFolder); %// Create image set
featureMatrix = encode(bag,imgSet).'; %// Encode the images - Make sure you transpose
```

The result will be a `M x N` matrix where `M` is the total number of input images you have and `N` is the total number of features.  To respect the neural networks toolbox, you **must** transpose this matrix because each **column** needs to be an input sample, not each row.

Comment: Thanks so much. I wasn't sure if featureVector vector would save the same purpose as an actual set of SURF or SIFT features obtained from an image. This helps me a lot.

Comment: @user2802349 - You're very welcome.  Well, a bag of words is essentially a feature vector, but you are describing images in a different way.  SURF / SIFT describe each keypoint with an orientation histogram mixed with a difference of Gaussians in a 128 bin vector.  You are just representing the images with another feature vector - each element is how much a particular keyword is used to describe the image.  All in all, they are the same thing, but you are just using different features / representations for classification.